# handling with multiple spec files

Tags: javascript, protractor

Can anyone please step how should i handle multiple spec file in protractor? I want to have a run sheet which list all spec file names and a column Excecute with all of them. I can then put 'Y' or 'N' in column i want to execute any particular spec file.

I tried to load this in Json File like this.

`"[{"Spec Files":"spec1.spec.js","Execute":"Y"},
{"Spec Files":"spec2.js","Execute":"Y"},
{"Spec Files":"Spec3.js","Execute":"N"}]"`

But I am unable to load this JSON file and loop through in Config.js where i am calling my spec file.

Answer (score 1):

Importing your json should be as simple as a `require` statement:

```
var j = require('path/to/your/file.json');
// Your json will look like :
[
    {"Spec Files":"spec1.spec.js","Execute":"Y"},
    {"Spec Files":"spec2.js","Execute":"Y"},
    {"Spec Files":"Spec3.js","Execute":"N"}
]
// X will be the var you use as your spec files collection:
var x = [];
for (obj in j) {
    if (j[obj].Execute === "Y") {
        x.push(j[obj]["Spec Files"]);
    }
}

// x will look like:
["spec1.spec.js", "spec2.js"]
```

### EDIT:

Your conf.js file should look along the lines of:

```
// Possible other imports
var json_file = require('./RunOrder.json');

var x = [];
for (obj in j) {
    if (j[obj].Execute === "Y") {
        x.push(j[obj]["Spec Files"]);
    }
}

exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: { 
    'browserName': 'chrome' 
  },
  specs: x
  // Possible other configuration settings
};
```

Comment: Hey Tom, where should i have this code? If i put in my Conf.js file and have all Execute as N, protractor is throwing an error saying cinfiguration file Conf.js did not export a config object.

Comment: This is the code i have`var testdata = require('./RunOrder.json');
var jsonlength = testdata.length;
for (var i=0; i<jsonlength;i++){
  var specfile = testdata[i].SpecFiles;
  var executeSpec = testdata[i].Execute;
  if (executeSpec == 'Y'){
    exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    specs: [‘specfile’],
    capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome' },
    params: {},
         onPrepare: function() {},
         }, 
        }
        else
        {
         export.config = {}
          
        }
        }`

Comment: tried with below code and it is still now working
`" var testdata = require('./RunOrder.json');
var jsonlength = testdata.length;

console.log(jsonlength);
//new method
var x = []
for (obj in testdata) {
    if (testdata[obj].Execute === "Y") {
        x.push(testdata[obj]["Spec Files"]);
  console.log("Entered loop");
    }
}
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome' },
  specs: [x],
};  "`

Comment: This is the error i am getting

`C:\Users\akuchhal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:155
                throw e;
                ^

TypeError: glob pattern string required`

Comment: Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can try to use `exclude` config parameter to ignore some spec files, check this: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L115

2) You can override what spec file to run with command line argument: `--specs relative/path/to/your_spec_file_or_pattern_*.js`

Can this help?

Comment: Thanks. This help but i am looking to control something dynamically. I have hundred of spec files for each page. If i do it that way i have to make lot of changes always in my run order sheet. I want a way where i can control my run order from outside like an excel or JSON file so that i just have to put Y in front of test case i want to execute.